# Force streamlit to run in specific python version (or under specific environment)

Tags: python, environment, python-venv, streamlit

I have a streamlit app that is set to run by doubleclicking a *.bat file that contains the command to start the app: streamlit run myApp.py. Does anyone know how to force that app to run in specific python version? My base python is 3.9, I created an environment (conda env create ...) based on python 3.6 where I installed streamlit and created the app and I want it to run there. I open sypder using that environment, double-checked that the env is active (!python --version in the spyder console) but when I run the app using the *bat file, it shows that is running in python 3.8!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/path/to/your/python -m streamlit run

Comment: This works!  I am using Mac terminal. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Although Streamlit is a Python library (and used to be a stand-alone company), `streamlit run myApp.py` in that context is a reference to an executable `streamlit`. In cases where there are multiple, you can specify the exact one you want to use:

`/path/to/conda/env/streamlit run myApp.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can run specific version of python like this from terminal:
`$ python3.10 -m streamlit run app.py`

On Windows like:
`$ py -3.10 -m streamlit run app.py`